# Do email providers junk all email from certain IP address ranges?

Tags: vps, spam, microsoft-office-365

**TLDR: Outlook.com appear to be junking all our emails from new VPS - nothing has an effect so questioning if IP address range reputation is the issue.**

We used to host all our websites (five) and email on a single VPS. Due to email problems that we were unable to resolve we obtained another server from a different company (Hostinger) to host our email.

Everything has been set up ok as far as we know - SPF, DKIM, DMARC, reverse DNS, correct HELO etc. are all in place and we have tested our email set-up using MX Toolbox, Mail-tester.com and IntoDNS. Our emails have literally been scored 10/10 according to Mail tester.

Further test emails to Gmail and Hotmail confirmed that SPF, DKIM and DMARC have all passed the checks.
Despite this, large numbers of emails to our customers have been going into their junk folder - including long standing customers we have had no problem sending to in the past.

Nearly always, these incidents are to customers using Outlook.com as their mail provider - according to their MX records.

Even when we are replying to an email they originally sent to us it goes into junk. Our customers are marking our emails as 'not-junk' and then still the next one goes into junk.

Our IP address was on a blacklist before we started using it but we got it removed immediately.

We were then added to the UCEPROTECTL3 blacklist for a short while which, as I understand it, is as a result of activity from an IP address range rather than a single IP address.

We contacted our provider and got our IP address changed although the new one was very similar - ending in 207 as opposed to 215.

They have also avoided answering my questions about how we got onto that list and they insist that our IP address is perfectly fine.

I also read a couple of blog posts recently including:

> Investigating this took a long time and it came out that there was a problem with various providers. They had "safe" ip's which they allowed and all the rest where just blocked and considered spam. This means that if you have an IP outside of a known and trusted range from a serious Web Hosting company then expect to have bad luck.

*did have a link but had to remove*

A previous ServerFault question had this as part of the answer:

> If the only factor is your IP and you don't mail often, this might be "the reputation of the /24 my IP is in". If you mail a lot, you might get your own reputation.

> The easiest way to get reputation which "drowns out" the IP reputation of your netblock is to set up DKIM. Send your mails signed. This will establish a per-domain reputation, instead of per-IP reputation, and provides more signal to the automated scoring systems.
> *did have a link but had to remove*

However, I *do* have DKIM set up and test emails confirm that the checks have passed successfully.

So my question is, Do Microsoft (and/or other providers) automatically junk emails from certain IP address ranges?
If so is there anything, realistically, that I can do with our VPS to ensure emails get through?

*some details removed due to, ironically, being accused of looking like spam...*

Comment: UCEPROTECT is an extortion racquet. If you can't find some other way to get Microsoft to accept your mail, you can try using an SMTP proxy service, inform Microsoft recipients that they their service is blocking legitimate standards-following emails, or just not communicate with Microsoft emails. Unless you want to feed these racquets, my personal recommendation is a very vocal and strong approach, or you will be paying Microsoft, Google, or Apple for their email service within the next 10 years.

Comment: Make sure your HELO matches your PTR for the IP. And yes ranges seen as dynamic or consumer are often blocked. Other ranges often seen is also commonly blocked. Office365 admins can check their mail logs and report your mails as not spam to MS, if enough do you should be cleared. Other than that change IP or provider.

Comment: @Paul It does seem a bit like extortion when Microsoft seem to cause the problem and then try and sell you the solution. I would like to run this email server but I do feel like I'm being squeezed out. Also, the boss wants to see immediate results so I fear we will be looking at one of those email services before long...

Comment: @NiKiZe thanks for the advice - this is one thing that we checked early on and, although initially it was slightly incorrect, it has been set correctly for quite a while now.

Comment: @JimboVader Eventually, you will be out of a job because your boss will cave to the extortion racquets, which ultimately seek to replace you, completely.

Comment: @Paul have I caught you on a bad day..? ;-)